# limit the number of ticks on time series x axis (d3)

Tags: d3.js, time-series, bar-chart, axis, xticks

Trying to create a bar chart with Time type on x axis. I want to only display few ticks on x axis. Below is a small portion of the code. After reading many posts online, I realized I need to use tickValues and also to Time format them. However, still getting a messy x axis. what I am doing wrong?

```
var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%Y");
g.append("g")
         .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
         .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)
         .tickValues(parseDate(["1890","2000"])))
         .append("text")
         .attr("y", height - 250)
         .attr("x", width - 100)
         .attr("text-anchor", "end")
         .attr("stroke", "black")
         .text("Year");
```

[image]

Comment: I bet 5000rp that `xScale` is a band scale.

Comment: It was :)   I changed it to scaleTime and then changed the Domain and now looks great! Thank you!

Comment: @baharakAl it'd be great if you answered your own question here with what was wrong